# How convert mail body from iso-8859-2 into utf-8

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, data-conversion

I'm using JavaMail to handle mail from my mailbox, and I have a following problem.

The content type of a mail is: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-2` (that's only in this case, I have to handle various mails with cp-1250 and many others).

And to get the body of this mail I'm using:

`mimeMessage.getContent().toString()`

and the content of the mail is returned but is not converted into utf-8, it's still in iso-8859-2 with causes generate text:

`w ďż˝omďż˝y.` instead of `w Łomży`.

How can I handle bodies with different than utf-8 encoding to convert it to utf? Is there any possibility to make it in JavaMail, that means JavaMail can convert an mail body from defined charset into utf-8?

Comment: Your example suggests that `UTF-8` bytes are being interpreted as `ISO-8859-2`. Show your code.

Comment: JavaMail uses the charset converters in the JDK to convert the (encoded) bytes in the email message into Java Unicode Strings.  If you think that's not working correctly, I need to see a reproducible test case.  Start by making sure that the data is actually in the charset it says it is; some broken mailers will list the wrong charset for the data.

Comment: I was found a problem which case this issue. I was opened this file (eml) in IDE and chars encoding was changed. That was causing a problem with the properly endcoding chars in the email.